# Beautiful Soup find href inside a child element

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, parent-child

I already tried different solutions, but I can't get the `href` inside the `<a>` element. 
I can reach the div class with `soup.select("div.quicklinks")` but then I do not know how to take the `href` with `title=Details`.

[image]

Thnaks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using:-

```
divElement.find("a", { "title" : "Details" })
```

Comment: use .find() or .select_one() for selecting the <div> element instead of .select(), because .select() returns the list of elements and .find() returns the first element matching the condition.

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
link = soup.find('div').find('a').get('href')
```

this should work without knowing the infos before the div

Answer (score 1):

Use the following:-

```
soup.select("div.quicklinks").find("a", title="Details")
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
urls=[]
result=driver.find_elements_by_class_name("quicklinks")
for res in result:
    url=res.find_element_by_tag_name("a").get_attribute("href")
    urls.append(url)
for u in urls:
    driver.get(u)
```

i have no idea about beautiful soup but u can make url scrapping from above code